# What is a word for people who frequently hypothesize?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word or a short phrase for people who frequently hypothesize and contemplate. Please help me out. I need use this word to give a title to an article that deals with such people as I've described. These are just general people, who happen to dream and ponder a lot over hypothetical possibilities.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are thinking of. Maybe you can start by checking out if these words work for you: *dreamer*, *theorist*, and *visionary*.

Comment: You mean, like Einstein did? You could help us out by giving a little more context about how you'd like to use the word.

Comment: J.R. I need to give a title to an article that deals with such people as I've described.

Comment: @battery - That tidbit helps a lot. I might use a different word in an article than I would in conversation. In general, you'll get better answers if  you provide better background information.

Comment: @battery Do these people share an occupation? "Scientists" for example? Or are these essentially just random people on the street who share a propensity for contemplation?

Comment: @Alexander these are just general people.

Comment: A contemplator is a serious person having deep thinking, on the other hand a person thinking hypothetical all time is thinking tentatively and **might not be** so serious.

Comment: @battery, you need to be more specific.  People that suffer from paranoid delusions hypothesize compulsively, but they're not dreamers, theorists or visionaries.

Answer (score 2):

I might go with just calling these people "thinkers". Depending on what you want to get across you might consider "day-dreamers" or "philosophers" as well.

Comment: Or "scientists," depending on the context.

Comment: I like `cogitators`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're describing a [Myers-Briggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator) personality type called [INTP](http://www.personalitypage.com/INTP.html).

Some various names:

- More formal with positive connotations: thinker, intellectual, philosopher, scientist, genius
- Neutral: Einstein
- Negative: geek, Absent-minded professor, brainiac, brain,
- Negative: egghead

Some people will proudly call themselves anything like a geek or an absent-minded professor, while others don't like being called Einstein or a genius etc.

The most accurate designation would be INTP Personality Type. What you use depends on what type of article you are writing.

Comment: Egghead isn't considered pejorative in the UK. It's often a label worn with pride.